# How to get a child element by id by its parent id element using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In the given code below, the `div#item-1` of the `div#parent-1` was only hidden.

**But how can i do that by specifying the parent?**

AND

**How can i do that by hiding both the `#item-1` element?**

```js
function HideElement(id)
{
 var doc = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    doc.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

HideElement('item-1');
```

```css
#parent-1
{
  background: red;
}

#parent-2
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-1">
  <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item-3">Item 3</div>
</div>

<div id="parent-2">
  <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item-3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

I replace the child element `id` attribute to `class` but the problem is how can i access the style property of the element?

I've got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined
```

Comment: Same ids within a same page??

Comment: ``id`` attribute should be unique across your whole page, so you have to change the second ``item-1``, ``item-2`` and ``item-3`` (children of ``parent-2``) occurrences to something else (or use ``class`` instead) to make it work properly.

Comment: oh it is possible right?

Comment: oh thanks for pointing out

Comment: using plain old javascript, you can do something along the lines of `document.getElementById('someId').querySelector(\`[data-id='${someId}']\`)` if you take the `data-id` approach. Something similar is possible with class names and ids, but as mentioned above, don't reuse ids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit:** I've taken some of the recommendations in the comments and put them into this answer.

You're better off using `class` or `data-` attributes instead of `id`s. As pointed out `id`s should be unique, so there can be only one of each on a page. Consider the following `html` & `js`:

```
<div id="parent-1">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent-2">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.item-hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

javascript:

```
function hideElement(selector){

  var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

  for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; ++i){
    items[i].classList.add('item-hidden');
  }

}

//usage:
hideElement('.item-1'); // will hide all '.item-1' elements
hideElement('#parent-1 div'); // will hide all <div>s inside of #parent-1
```

[querySelectorAll() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[classList reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

**edit:** About the update on the question:

`document.getElementsByClassName();` will return a `nodelist`, instead of just one `node`. Notice the 's' in getElement**s**ByClassName. You'll have to use a loop like in this answer to change properties for each node.

Comment: I'll try this one

Comment: Better to take a selector as input of the function - instead of forcing a class - that way it can be used to target elements in a better way... `#parent-1 .item-1` for example, since the question mentioned also specifying the parent in one case

Comment: @tewathia +1 for this i really need to get  the parent's ids also.

Comment: Also, adding a class using JavaScript that hides the element  (`visibility:hidden` or `display:none`) instead of hiding it programmatically might be better. That will also bypass the visibility property error

Comment: It also encourages better separation of concerns. JavaScript usually shouldn't describe how an element is styled, only whether it is or isn't in the DOM and its properties (exception: absolute positioning, complex animation)

Comment: @DanPantry; @tewathia:  I've taken your comments and included them in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use data- attribute and simply play with them. Like in your example, you can use `data-id="item-1"` and this will do the game.

Reference to [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).